# How to get details of people having birthday on today from database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the below query which gets details of people selected according to the month in my php project.So it displays me the list of people who have birthdays on this month. But I really want is to get the list of people who have birthdays on today. Please help me to change this query...

```
select * from customer_info
  where date_format(str_to_date(b_day, '%Y-%m-%d'), '%m') = MONTH(NOW());
```

Comment: How about comparing b_day = NOW() without year and time part?

Comment: @Akisha if the guys solved your issue you should flag one of the answers as accepted :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using `month()` and `day()`?

```
select ci.*
from customer_info ci
where month(b_day) = month(curdate()) and day(b_dat) = day(curdate());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customer_info
WHERE
    MONTH(b_day) = MONTH(NOW()) AND
    DAY(b_day) = DAY(NOW())
```

Comment: Yes this query is also working for me.. Thank you..:)